# How do I install the QtWebKit 3.0 module for Qt Creator?

Tags: 12.10, application-development, qt, qml, qt5

I'm trying to add a webview to my project, but the module isn't installed.  I'm new to qml and qt and I'm not sure how to install the module.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In default 12.10 it seems to be provided by `libqtwebkit4`. But that package is from Qt4, so I suppose you are using qt5-edgers ppa to provide Qt5. There you have two packages that can solve your problem:

```
sudo apt-get install libqt5webkit5-qmlwebkitplugin libqt5webkit5
```

So if you are using that PPA install those two packages and see if it solves your problem. If not you can use `apt-cache` to try to find the right package:

```
apt-cache search libqt*webkit*
```

If you can't find anything, you can try to use the Qt4 package I stated above, but I doubt it would help anything.

Hope it helps.